Node.js application that integrates with the Wit.ai API to recognize user intents from their input. "
I'm currently working on a Node.js application that integrates with the Wit.ai API to recognize user intents from their input. While my server is successfully processing the requests, I keep receiving the response: "Goal processed successfully, but intent not recognized."
Added Sample Phrases: I’ve incorporated various sample phrases in my Wit.ai app for the intended goals, but I’m still encountering the error "Intent not recognized."
Testing in Postman: I’ve directly tested the Wit.ai API in Postman with different phrases, but I did not achieve successful intent recognition.
Validated API Token: I confirmed that my Wit.ai API token is valid and has the appropriate permissions for use.
